# How to fix "Property htmlFor does not exist" on Custom React element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this custom component :

```
import React from "react";
import classnames from 'classnames';

import { ButtonVariantColor } from '../types/button';

export type IconButtonProps = {
    element?: React.ElementType
    icon: React.ElementType
    variantColor?: ButtonVariantColor | string | undefined
} & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement & HTMLLabelElement>


export default function IconButton({ 
    className,
    element = 'button',
    icon,
    variantColor = ButtonVariantColor.default,
    ...props
}:IconButtonProps) {
    const Icon = icon;
    const ButtonElement = element;
    
    if (!(variantColor in ButtonVariantColor)) {
        variantColor = ButtonVariantColor.default;
    }

    return (
        <ButtonElement className={ classnames('btn btn-circle border-none text-base-content', {
            'bg-inherit hover:bg-gray-300 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:bg-gray-700': variantColor === ButtonVariantColor.default,
            'bg-blue-200 hover:bg-blue-400 dark:bg-blue-900 dark:hover:bg-blue-700': variantColor === ButtonVariantColor.info,
            'bg-green-300 hover:bg-green-500 dark:bg-green-900 dark:hover:bg-green-700': variantColor === ButtonVariantColor.success,
            'bg-orange-200 hover:bg-orange-400 dark:bg-orange-700 dark:hover:bg-orange-500': variantColor === ButtonVariantColor.warning,
            'bg-red-200 hover:bg-red-400 dark:bg-red-900 dark:hover:bg-red-600': variantColor === ButtonVariantColor.error,
        }, className) } { ...props }>
            <Icon />
        </ButtonElement>
    );
};
```

and it is being used like this :

```
<IconButton element="label" icon={ ChevronLeftIcon } htmlFor={ menuId } />
```

However, `htmlFor` has an error and I don't know how to fix it. If the properties are inheriting from both `HTMLButtonElement & HTMLLabelElement`, why does it complain about `htmlFor` missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to fix "Property htmlFor does not exist"

tl;dr - `HTMLAttributes` does not include `htmlFor` prop.

`HTMLAttributes` resolves to `AriaAttributes`, `DOMAttributes` and *common* html attributes.. `AriaAttributes` stands for the *accessibility* properties and `DOMAttributes` stands for *common* properties for DOM elements (mostly handlers). `htmlFor` **is not** a common prop, it's unique only for `Label` element.

Solution: you should be using `HTMLLabelElement` type instead.

```
export type IconButtonProps = {
  ...
} & HTMLButtonElement & HTMLLabelElement;
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up needing a union between my custom props and `React.LabelHTMLAttributes<HTMLLabelElement> & React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>`.